# JQuery error on javascript document null or undefined

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am recieving the following error when trying to execte the java script listed below in the page load event of an aspx web page.

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'document': object is null or undefined

```
Dim scriptString As String = ("<script>javascript: window.opener.document.forms(0).submit(); </script>")
If Not Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(scriptString) Then
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "script", scriptString)
End If
```

I am trying to produce a postback.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On a side note: forms is an array, not a method. It should be using square bracket notation. `forms[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.opener) -

> When a window is opened from another window, it maintains a reference
>   to that first window as window.opener. If the current window has no
>   opener, this method returns NULL.

Is it possible that the page your script is being called from has no opener? That would explain the `document` reference being null.

Comment: Well on Page Load, the popup is not yet called or opened. So I added code to check if a postback is occuring. It passes over this code on first page load. But after the popup is opened, it still throws this error.

Comment: You could try this - `<script>javascript: if (window.opener) window.opener.document.forms(0).submit(); </script>`

Comment: It still doesnt seem to activate a postback.